# Multidimensional arrays sorting by inner Multidimensional arrays key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

What is the easiest way to sort the array using the time-stamp? For example; the array key 19 needs to be the first one after sorting because key 1494238836 is the highest in the inner array.

```
    $testArray = array (
        17 =>
              array (
                  1490011261 =>
                    (object)(array('test15')),
              ),
         1 =>
          array (
              1491898801 =>
                (object)(array('test14')),
          ),
        25 =>
        array (
            1491474454 =>
                (object)(array('test1')),
            1491474657 =>
                (object)(array('test5'))
        ),
        19 =>
            array (
                1494238836 =>
                (object)(array('test1')),
        ),


    );
```

Comment: Where do the objects originate from?

Comment: what is your desired output?

Comment: @Doug I created this from a dump of a multidimensional array that has an object of customer class. In this case the object will not matter but the key(timestamp) holding the object determines what position the outer array keys

Comment: @Bhaskar The array needs to be in this sorted order 19,1,25,17

Comment: @CharlesPhiri Your code is working or you are stuck somewhere?

Comment: @Bhaskar the code is working now. Not sure if thats the best way of doing it but its giving me the right results

Comment: The reason I asked is, if the data originates from a database. Do the sorting at that level.

Answer (score 0):

So I did something like this:

```
    $sortArray = array();
    foreach ($testArray as $key =>$value){
        $maxKey = max(array_keys($value));
        $sortArray[$maxKey] = $key;
    }
    krsort($sortArray);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_export($sortArray);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";

    //Testing the theory
    foreach($sortArray as $key =>$value)
    {
        echo "<br/> Main Key:";
        echo $value;
        echo "<pre>";
        var_export($testArray[$value]);
        echo "</pre>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "___________________________";

    }
```